# Inverse matrix in Haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix, inverse

I just started to learn Haskell.
And I have a question. I trying write a function to find the inverse matrix.
My type of matrix looks like that:

```
data Matrix a = M 
    { nrows :: !Int
    , ncols :: !Int
    , mvect :: V.Vector (V.Vector a)
    } deriving Eq
```

Also I have `fromLists` function.
The function for finding the determinant looks like that:

```
det :: Num a => Matrix a -> a
det (M 1 1 v) = V.head (V.head v)
det m =
    sum [ (-1)^(i-1) * m ! (i,1) * det (minorMatrix i 1 m) | i <- [1 .. nrows m] ]
```

So, my code for finding the inverse matrix:

```
coords :: Matrix a -> [[(Int, Int)]]
coords = zipWith (map . (,)) [0..] . map (zipWith const [0..])

delmatrix :: Int -> Int -> Matrix a -> Matrix a
delmatrix i j = dellist i . map (dellist j)
    where dellist i xs = take i xs ++ drop (i + 1) xs

mapMatrix :: (a -> a) -> Matrix a -> Matrix a
mapMatrix f = map (map f)

cofactor :: Num a => Int -> Int -> Matrix a -> a
cofactor i j m = ((-1) ** fromIntegral (i + j)) * det (delmatrix i j m)

cofactorM :: Matrix a -> Matrix a
cofactorM m = map (map (\(i,j) -> cofactor j i m)) $ coords m

inverse :: (Num a, Fractional a) => Matrix a -> Matrix a
inverse m = mapMatrix (* recip deter) $ cofactorM m
    where deter = det m
```

And what I have on a console:

```
Prelude> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling Matrixlab        ( Matrixlab.hs, interpreted )

Matrixlab.hs:120:38:
    Couldn't match expected type `Matrix a' with actual type `[a0]'
    Expected type: Matrix a -> [[Int]]
      Actual type: [a0] -> [b0]
    In the return type of a call of `map'
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely
      `map (zipWith const [0 .. ])'

Matrixlab.hs:123:17:
    Couldn't match expected type `Matrix a' with actual type `[a0]'
    Expected type: [a0] -> Matrix a
      Actual type: [a0] -> [a0]
    In the return type of a call of `dellist'
    In the first argument of `(.)', namely `dellist i'

Matrixlab.hs:127:15:
    Couldn't match expected type `Matrix a' with actual type `[a0]'
    Expected type: Matrix a -> Matrix a
      Actual type: [a0] -> [b0]
    In the return type of a call of `map'
    In the expression: map (map f)

Matrixlab.hs:130:24:
    Could not deduce (Floating a) arising from a use of `**'
    from the context (Num a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 cofactor :: Num a => Int -> Int -> Matrix a -> a
      at Matrixlab.hs:130:1-71
    Possible fix:
      add (Floating a) to the context of
        the type signature for
          cofactor :: Num a => Int -> Int -> Matrix a -> a
    In the first argument of `(*)', namely
      `((- 1) ** fromIntegral (i + j))'
    In the expression:
      ((- 1) ** fromIntegral (i + j)) * det (delmatrix i j m)
    In an equation for `cofactor':
        cofactor i j m
          = ((- 1) ** fromIntegral (i + j)) * det (delmatrix i j m)

Matrixlab.hs:133:15:
    Couldn't match expected type `Matrix a' with actual type `[[a]]'
    In the expression:
      map (map (\ (i, j) -> cofactor j i m)) $ coords m
    In an equation for `cofactorM':
        cofactorM m = map (map (\ (i, j) -> cofactor j i m)) $ coords m
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Help me, please.

Comment: For errors 1, 2, 3, and 5, it looks like you're trying to use a matrix as a list, which obviously won't work.  You'll have to use the `Vector` operations instead of the `Prelude` ones, and you'll have to make sure to extract the `mvect` from each `Matrix` before being able to use them.

Comment: On another note, maybe you could try tackling each problem in isolation?  What happens if you comment out all the functions but `coords` and reload it?  You should get the same error, but it'll only be one error message, not 5.  Study that error message (it tells you exactly what the problem was, couldn't match the types `Matrix a` and `[a0]` in the expression `map (zipWith const [0..])`).  What if you then comment out the type signature for `coords` and recompile?  It'll probably compile, but then inspect it's type with `:type` in GHCi, is it what you were expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you want to use vectors, you should use vectors. If you are going to convert them back and from lists all the time, you should just stick with lists. The vector package provides all of the functions you have on lists for the `Vector` type. So you should be using those. In fact, it will almost always be easier to work with the `Vector` functions, since they give you built-in access to the index of an item. [If you don't know what functions you have available, take a look at the docs.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.9.2)

You also can't pretend that your `Matrix` is equivalent to a list of lists and expect the compiler to know what you're talking about. You have to take the vectors out of the `Matrix` constructor using pattern matching, operate on them, and put them back in. For example:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V

cofactorM :: Floating a => Matrix a -> Matrix a
cofactorM m@(M x y v) = M x y $ (V.imap $ \i -> V.imap $ \j -> const (cofactor i j m)) v 

cofactor :: Floating a => Int -> Int -> Matrix a -> a
cofactor ...
```

Keep in mind that `Vector` is zero indexed, while your `det` function implies that your columns and rows are one indexed. You will have to compensate for this.

Lastly, there is no good reason to package the number of rows and columns in with the `Vector (Vector a)` since getting the length of a vector is a constant time operation anyways.

Comment: I understand a little of what you've written. Thank you so much. If it's not too much trouble for you, could you please rewrite other functions?

Comment: If you don't care about how this works and just need it for some other project, then use one of the many linear algebra packages that already exist. If you are writing this code as part of learning, then me writing it for you isn't going to help much is it?